# JQuery - element not copied?

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble copying an element in my page DOM. Here's the code of the element I want to copy:

```
<fieldset class="step" id="person2_dummy">
    <legend>Persoonskaart 2</legend>
    <ul class="form_column">
        <li><label for="nickname_2">Roepnaam</label><input type="text" class="inputtext required" id="nickname_2_dummy" name="person2[nickname]"></li>
        <li><label for="prepositions_2">Tussenvoegsel(s)</label><input type="text" class="inputtext" id="prepositions_2_dummy" name="person2[prepositions]"></li>
        <li><label for="surname_2">Achternaam</label><input type="text" class="inputtext required" id="surname_2_dummy" name="person2[surname]"></li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li><label for="bdate_day_2">Geboortedatum</label>
            <select class="required" name="person2[bdate_day]" id="bdate_day_2_dummy">
                <option value="">--</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
            <select class="required" name="person2[bdate_month]" id="bdate_month_2_dummy">
                <option value="">--</option>
                <option value="1">januari</option>
            </select>
            <select class="required" name="person2[bdate_year]" id="bdate_year_2_dummy">
                <option value="">--</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li><label for="sex_2">Geslacht</label><select class="inputselect required" id="sex_2_dummy" name="person2[sex]">
            <option value="MALE">Man</option>
            <option value="FEMALE">Vrouw</option>
        </select></li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li><label for="national_id_2">BSN / Sofinummer</label><input type="text" class="inputtext required" id="national_id_2_dummy" name="person2[national_id]"><a class="tooltip" href="#" oldtitle="Uitleg BSN/Sofienummer"><img alt="" src="/cmsfile/70"></a></li>
            <li><label for="second_driver">Tweede bestuurder</label><input type="checkbox" class="inputtext" id="second_driver_dummy" name="second_driver"></li>
            <li style="visibility: hidden;" id="li_second_driver"><label for="license_2_dummy">Rijbewijsnummer</label><input type="text" class="inputtext" id="license_2_dummy" name="person2[license]"><script type="text/javascript">/*&lt;![CDATA[*/ 
            $("#second_driver").click(function() {
                if ($("#second_driver").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#li_second_driver").css("visibility", "visible");
                    $("#license_2").addClass("required");
                } else {
                    $("#li_second_driver").css("visibility", "hidden");
                    $("#license_2").removeClass("required");
                }
                determineOrderType();
            }); /*]]&gt;*/</script><br clear="all"></li>
        <li><label for="ice_1_2">Alarmnummer 1</label><input type="text" class="inputtext required" id="ice_1_2_dummy" name="person2[ice_1]"><a class="tooltip" href="#" oldtitle="Uitleg alarmnummer"><img alt="" src="/cmsfile/70"></a></li>
        <li><label for="ice_2_2">Alarmnummer 2</label><input type="text" class="inputtext" id="ice_2_2_dummy" name="person2[ice_2]"></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <label for="no-allergies_2_dummy">Geen allergieen</label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="no-allergies_2_dummy" value="no-allergies" name="person2[allergies][]">
        <label for="no-blood-thinners_2_dummy">Geen bloedverdunners</label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="no-blood-thinners_2_dummy" value="no-blood-thinners" name="person2[bloodthinners][]">
        <label for="no-heart-diseases_2_dummy">Geen hartaandoeningen</label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="no-heart-diseases_2_dummy" value="no-heart-diseases" name="person2[heartdiseases][]">
    </div>
    <div class="form_column" id="medical_info_2_dummy">
        <ul class="form_medical">
            <li><em>Medische allergieen</em></li>
            <li><label for="lodine_2">Jodium</label>        <input type="checkbox" id="lodine_2_dummy" value="lodine" name="person2[allergies][]" class="inputcheckbox"></li>
            <li><label for="antibiotics_2">Antibiotica</label>  <input type="checkbox" id="antibiotics_2_dummy" value="antibiotics" name="person2[allergies][]"></li>
            <li><label for="contrast_2">Contrast</label>        <input type="checkbox" id="contrast_2_dummy" value="contrast" name="person2[allergies][]"></li>
            <li><label for="latex_2">Latex</label>      <input type="checkbox" id="latex_2_dummy" value="latex" name="person2[allergies][]"></li>
            <li><label for="penicillin_2">Penicilline</label>   <input type="checkbox" id="penicillin_2_dummy" value="penicillin" name="person2[allergies][]"></li> 

            <li><em>Hartaandoeningen</em></li>
            <li><label for="pacemaker_2">Pacemaker / ICD</label>    <input type="checkbox" id="pacemaker_2_dummy" value="pacemaker" name="person2[heartdiseases][]"></li>
            <li><label for="beta-blocker_2">Betablocker</label> <input type="checkbox" id="beta-blocker_2_dummy" value="beta-blocker" name="person2[heartdiseases][]"></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="form_medical">
            <li><em>Gebruik van bloedverdunners</em></li>
            <li><label for="carbasalaatcalcium_2">Ascal</label> <input type="checkbox" id="carbasalaatcalcium_2_dummy" value="carbasalaatcalcium" name="person2[bloodthinners][]"></li>
            <li><label for="clopidogrel_2">Plavix</label>       <input type="checkbox" id="clopidogrel_2_dummy" value="clopidogrel" name="person2[bloodthinners][]"></li>
            <li><label for="acenocoumarol_2">Acenocoumarol</label><input type="checkbox" id="acenocoumarol_2_dummy" value="acenocoumarol" name="person2[bloodthinners][]"></li>
            <li><label for="fenprocoumon_2">Marcoumar</label>   <input type="checkbox" id="fenprocoumon_2_dummy" value="fenprocoumon" name="person2[bloodthinners][]"></li>

            <li><em>Overige</em></li>
            <li><label for="diabetes_2">Diabetes</label>        <input type="checkbox" id="diabetes_2_dummy" value="diabetes" name="person2[other][]"></li>
            <li><label for="deaf_2">Doof</label>            <input type="checkbox" id="deaf_2_dummy" value="deaf" name="person2[other][]"></li>
        </ul>
    </div><script type="text/javascript">/*&lt;![CDATA[*/ 
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#medical_info_2_dummy").find("input").each(function() {
                $(this).click(function() {
                    handleMedical(2, $(this));
                });
            });
        }); /*]]&gt;*/</script></fieldset>
```

I'm trying to copy the person2_dummy element, remove all _dummy id's and insert it after another element on the page. Like so:

```
    var number = 2;
var after = $('#person1'); // <-- yes, this does exist

$("#person"+number+"_dummy").clone().attr("id", "person" + number).find("input, select, div").each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
    $(this).attr("id", function(){
        var attr = $(this).attr("id");
        return attr.replace("_dummy", "");
    })
}).end().insertAfter(after);
```

But, nothing happens when I try this. Any clues on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just curious, why are you setting the `id` twice? If you want it generic, the `.attr()` handler gets args, like this: `.attr("id", function(i, id) { return id.replace("_dummy",""); })` ...no need for the `.each()` looping and such :)

Comment: _Something_ happens. Put some debug alerts in. Use Firebug to spot errors. Use breakpoints to track script execution.

Comment: @Nick This bit of code used to also change other attributes. So, you mean: $("#person"+number+"_dummy").clone().attr("id", function(i, id) { return id.replace("_dummy", "");}).end().insertAfter(after); ?

Comment: @Tomalak: I've tried this, in fact there's one of these test alerts still in this code :) I've tried alerting before and after this code, it all works. No errors in Firebug either, I did do some homework before posting on here.

Comment: @Robbert - almost, use that function wherever needed, for example `.find("whatever").andSelf().attr(....like I have above...).end().end().insertAfter()`, or a bit cleaner would be to insert then change the IDs, whichever really.

Comment: Promises like "yes, this does exist" don't fill me with confidence when I can't see the proof.

Comment: Your code is working see HERE http://jsfiddle.net/gubhaju/CP2Z7/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, crap.

I'm going to blame my colleague for adding a dodgy version of a tooltip plugin. The code worked on jFiddle so it had to be something on the rest of the page. Although it wasn't throwing errors, the component messed up this javascript. Grr.

So, I removed the plugin (qTip btw) and everything was working like a charm!
Thanks a *lot* for the thoughts guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
var number = 2;
var after = $('#person1');

$("#person"+number+"_dummy").clone().insertAfter(after).find('[id]').each(function(i){
        var idAttr = $(this).attr('id');
        idAttr = idAttr.replace('_dummy', '');
        $(this).attr('id', idAttr);
    });
```

**EDIT:**
If that doesn't work your #person1 div/element doesn't exist or isn't being found.
If you change insert after to:

```
insertAfter("#person"+number+"_dummy")
```

It'll insert the div straight after the copied div. (see this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m2kSd/)

Comment: Yeah I've seen the edit, thanks but still no cigar. Thing is, even this doesn't work:
    $("#person"+number+"_dummy").clone().insertAfter(after);
So there must be something else going on?

Comment: btw, both the person1 and person2_dummy elements are found! (checked by alerting their .attr("id"))

Comment: You can find the full source code on: http://eurocodicilnlnewui.covide.nl/page/formulier.htm&new=1&prod=VB1.htm&newform=1
 (Sorry, it's all in Dutch :) )

Comment: by the way: there's a link in the top bit of the form that will try to add the fieldset to the DOM.